# Eigenvalues of $BB^\top$ and $B^\top B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B \in Mat_{n \times m}$

I get that $BB^\top$ and $B^\top B$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues since $B^\top B v=\lambda v \implies (BB^\top) B v=\lambda (Bv)$

What I do not understand is that how the above does not also prove that some zero eigenvalues overlap as well between $BB^\top$ and $B^\top B$ since $B^\top B v= 0 \implies (BB^\top) B v= 0$. This is of course assuming that $Bv$ is not $0$ so maybe not all the zero eigenvalues do overlap.

Comment: The "zero eigenvalues" may not exist for one of the two matrices, $BB^T$ and $B^TB$.  For example suppose $B$ is $1\times n$ is a nonzero row with $n\gt 1$.  Then $BB^T$ is a nonzero scalar (a $1\times 1$ matrix), but $B^T B$ will be an $n\times n$ matrix of rank one, so it will have nullity $n-1$.  It isn't really clear what it means for zero eigenvalues to "overlap".